# Classic asp - image display in a webpage

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I am working with classic asp. Very, very new to this. Now the ask is simple, I need to display a bunch of images (.jpeg) from an oracle table to the webpage. The issue is I am able to display all the images URL but, the actual images do not show up! I want the images, not their URL from the oracle table.

```
    <TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><%=img src("IMAGE_URL")%></TD>
```

This is where I am trying to put the image into the column, IMAGE_URL is the name of the column in the oracle table with all the URLs. I know I am wrong somewhere since I am so new to this and it's classic asp!

Comment: *"The issue is I am able to display all the images URL but, the actual images do not show up!"* - is the url accessible? html's [`img` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) shows image by telling the browser where to find them. also, what does `<%=img src("IMAGE_URL")%>` even outputs to? i do curious. i thought it had to be `<img src="<%= the_resolved_url %>">` or using [`<asp:Image>` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">
         <img src="<%=IMAGE_URL%>">
</TD>

You had the asp code making the html, instead of the html including the asp variable.